# Where am I making a mistake in switch condition?

Tags: javascript, switch-statement, conditional-statements

Where am I making a mistake?

```
var mod;
    var module = ((from - to) % mod == 0);
    switch (mod)
    {
        case 20:
            for (i = 20; i <= to - from; i = i + 20)
            {
                //console.log("case");
                CanYou(i, from, to)
            }
            break;

    }
```

I am raw to switch conditions, can anyone help me? I want to find a number which (some calculations) module is equal to 0;

Comment: Probably because `mod` is `undefined`. Did you mean to use `switch (module)` ?

Comment: If you have just one condition to test for use `if`. When having multiple outcomes, use `switch`.

Comment: Nitpicky, but for readability should `module` be `modulo`? As in the name of the `%` operator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var mod = 2; // need to init this to something
var module = ((from - to) % mod == 0);
switch (mod)
{
    case 20:
        for (i = 20; i <= to - from; i = i + 20)
        {
            //console.log("case");
            CanYou(i, from, to)
        }
        break;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your mod variable is undefined. Maybe you want switch module variable ?

```
var module = ((from - to) % mod == 0);
switch (module)
{
    case 20:
        for (i = 20; i <= to - from; i = i + 20)
        {
            //console.log("case");
            CanYou(i, from, to)
        }
        break;

}
```

Comment: It is not null, it is undefined. Yours will have a different issue if mod is still not set to a value.